# How to change X labels using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have created a graphic using JFreeChart (see image below). However, I want to change the labels into the X so instead of 1,2,3 and so, I can display for example the name of each section like Sports, Economy and such. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=117127

Comment: More examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SymbolAxis).

Comment: Are you using a CategoryDataSet with the values you want to show? For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_bar_chart.htm